# Why does the zipcode fail the check constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I feel like I am probably missing something really simple, but I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to use a check constraint to make sure zipcodes are 5 digit numbers, but the check restraint keeps failing. Here is the table creating with the constraint:

```
Create Table Students (
   StudentID Int Primary Key Identity(1,1)
   StudentNumber nVarchar(100) Unique Not Null,
   ...
   StudentZipCode nChar(10) Not Null
)
Go
Alter Table Students Add Constraint chZipCode
    CHECK (StudentZipCode LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' OR StudentZipCode 
    Like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
Go
```

Codes like 12345-6789 work, but when I try to insert the values like '12345' or '01234' it gives me this error:

The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chZipCode". The conflict occurred in database ..., table "dbo.Students", column 'StudentZipCode'.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Looks like you had a typo in your question you corrected.  It's often the case there's a similar error in a query with these types of questions.  Can you post the actual insert statement that's failing?

Comment: I meant '01234' instead of ''012344', which is what I typed originally.  @GordonLinoff's answer was the solution I was looking for, it just didn't let me accept the answer immediately.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because you defined the zip code as a `char()` instead of a `varchar()`.  Hence, it has a bunch of spaces padding it out.

So, define it as:

```
Create Table Students (
   StudentID Int Primary Key Identity(1,1),
   StudentNumber nVarchar(100) Unique Not Null,
   StudentZipCode nVarChar(10) Not Null,
   CHECK (StudentZipCode LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' OR
          StudentZipCode LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
);
```

Then `'12345'` works, because it matches the first of the `LIKE` patterns.

`'012344'` does not work, because no pattern has six digits in a row.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2c666/1) is a SQL Fiddle.